# how to parse this kind of JSON API by using SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

A project using Swift and parse a JSON API by using a library called SwiftyJSON

[{"A":1,
"B":"２",
"C":"３",
"D":"４"
},
{"A2":12,
"B3":"23",
"C4":"34",
"D5":"45"
}]

↑This is the API and This is the code↓

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController{


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

parseJSON()
}

func parseJSON(){

let path:String=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json")as String!
let jsonData=NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
let readableJSON=JSON(data:jsonData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil)

var　number=readableJSON["A"]

NSLog("\(number)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Somethings wrong and the API’s method is not a Dictionary.

I have to parse a JSON by anyway i could  so can somebody tell me the way to parse a API that it's method is an Array?

If you have any other way or alternative's for this project please teach me.

thanks for your cooperation

Comment: the project name is "JSON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer object of the json is an array ( `[]` -> array, `{}` -> dictionary).
The requested dictionary is the first element of the array.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json")!
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!
let readableJSON = JSON(data:jsonData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:nil)

if let number = readableJSON[0].dictionary?["A"] {
  println(number)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON does not represent a dictionary, but **an array of** dictionaries.

Thus

```
let firstDictionary = readableJSON[0]
var number = firstDictionary["A"]
```

will likely work.